# Mixing AutoLayout and Programmatically created UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, autolayout

I am having trouble mixing both an AutoLayout and Programmatically created layout.

I have a UIView in AutoLayout (the green box). I have other views that are using AutoLayout in this scene that work and are dependent upon autolayout, but for simplicity, I am only showing the problem area.

Depending on the state of the app, certain buttons will be placed in the green UIView. I calculate the size of the buttons by reading the size of the UIView, knowing how much space I want in between the buttons, and finally dividing that number by how many buttons. That doesn’t seem to be a problem.

**Though when I bring up the view, this happens:**

[image]

**But if the view is reloaded/refreshed, it works and looks like it should.**

[image]

It is only on the initial load that the view is messed up.

Outputting the UIView size at different states:

**Initial Load**

```
UIView Size: {240, 128}
```

**Reload (coming back to the screen or refreshing the data** 
*This is the correct size*

```
UIView Size: {288, 31}
```

I call my programmatically created buttons in `ViewDidLoad` method,

```
- (void) buildButtonGUI {
    //Show generic code

          somebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [somebutton  addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [somebutton  setTitle:@"ONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        somebutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        somebutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [somebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.viewStatus addSubview:somebutton];

    etc..

}
```

Then the program logic takes over **[self doLogic]**, and I hide / show buttons, and resize based upon logic that happens AFTER I call the buildButtonGUI

```
-   (void) doLogic {
//Do something with all the buttons and calculate the size needed

somebutton.frame = CGRectMake(StartXPos, 0, someCalculated.size.width, someCalculated.size.height);
somebutton.enabled = true;
somebutton.hidden = false;
etc..
}
```

I have tried many different options, by putting my **[self doLogic]** in viewWillAppear and viewHasAppeared etc..

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to do that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Layout happens after viewWillAppear

Comment: Do what? My logic? or adding the buttons?

Comment: That doesn't work, the ViewDidLayoutSubviews gets called continuously. Looks like it creates unnecessary overhead. Constantly checking and resizing the buttons. Doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: What is `calculated` variable? Try to call `layoutIfNeeded` before `doLogic`

Comment: This is exactly what `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is for, updating frames when the view bounds changes.

Comment: But throwing an NSLog in there you see it run about constantly.